# Does anybody recognize this kashrus symbol? Rectangle K US

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

[image: Image of food packaging showing the kashrus symbol]

As the title says, does anybody know this kosher symbol? It looks like a large K with the letters U and S on top and bottom of it, inside of a rectangle. The product brand is Super Cakes, subsidiary of Super Bread. A lot of their other products have this symbol, but I can't seem to find it online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is the trademark of ["United Kosher Supervision"](http://unitedkoshersupervision.com/), which is [apparently](http://www.torahindex.com/en/Inst/institutionsDetail.aspx?index=2&instID=4982) headed by a R' Yaakov Spivak of Monsey, NY.